# Developing Android OpenGL ES App with .NET and Visual Studio 2017

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, opengl-es, visual-studio-2017

As it is possible to develop Android apps in .NET (with Xamarin), is there also a way to make an OpenGL canvas and OpenGL calls?

I didnt find anything regarding this in the documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/

Comment: You have access to the Android framework, i.e. `Android.Opengl.*`, `Javax.Microedition.Khronos.*` ....

Comment: @SushiHangover how exactly do i get access to them? they cant be found in the dependencies.

Comment: They are a part of the Android Java framework that Xamarin wraps and exposes. `using Android.Opengl; using Javax.Microedition.Khronos;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Xamarin.Forms, it seems you are looking for the `OpenGLView`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.openglview?view=xamarin-forms

> A View that displays OpenGL content.

Currently it only supports Android and iOS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/views#openglview

Otherwise, as mentioned in the comments, you can just use the native Android frameworks for `OpenGL`. You will need something like this: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/ApiDemo/Graphics/CubeRenderer.cs